# Microservers VS Virtual Servers

Tags: virtualization, virtualhost, virtual-machines

I am reading this articles in regard to microservers :

[10 things you should know about microserver](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-things-you-should-know-about-microservers/#.)

[Microservers : What you need to know](http://www.zdnet.com/microservers-what-you-need-to-know-7000011486/)

It seems to conclude that micoservers are best tailored for serving static HTML pages and for doing the low level stuff

A very interesting comment left by one of the readers :

> I can't think of a use case in the business world for micro-servers.
>   If you don't need the full power of a multi-core 1U server, use a
>   virtual server. You could theoretically pack 100's of VM's that one
>   might run on a micro-server on a loaded DL360... consume only a few
>   hundred watts and only 1U of rack space

**I would like to know if packing 100's of VM into a multi-core 1U server is indeed superior to the same X number of microserver you can pack assuming the space required is the same as the 1U server??**

Can someone suggest a better title for the question , i feel the title is abit off

Answer (score 1):

Basically it runs all down to marketing or procesing power. No joke.

If you run a web hoster - and that is what microservers target - then this allows you to sell "real" servers to people. Avoids the bad connotation of (low end) virtual machines. It should practivally not make a large difference, and you loose flexibility (compared to vm's) but there are a lot of people burned by underpowered vm's.

You also ahve a lot more processing power per host - compared to packing all those VM's into a upper even mid range server. For some scenarios that may be relevant. I ahvea box in the basement for example with 16 blades and each has 8gb memory and a pathetic disc, but they run at 100% cpu - very hard to virtualize this.

Besides those two edge cases it IS hard to come up with a decent business case.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is really there in the articles you linked.  If you're a hosting company, or otherwise power thousands of servers, shifting computationally simple tasks to power-efficient servers based on the ARM chipset can save a lot of money.  If you can market them as dedicated servers and get people to prefer them over traditionally low-end VPSes, all the better, but the advantage is cost savings.

The hardware costs less, and cost less to run.  It adds up when you run a lot of servers.

Comment: Actually it does not really - because yo ucan run a virtual machine more efficiently financially. THe real reason is marketing - people not liking the virtual machine for various reasons.

Comment: @TomTom  Debatable, and assumes your normal servers are optimally configured for power efficiency, which they probably won't be.  At the very least, these microservers use less power per CPU cycle, so at least in theory, they can be run cheaper than a VM on a normal server.  Whether the real world effect of those energy savings actually adds up to anything significant, we probably won't know for sure until we have real-world data.  However, given the success of big outfits like Google using cheap, custom server hardware, I'd expect microservers to be capable of similar cost-saving benefits.